# Returning true in recursive function when atleast 1 condition is met

Tags: javascript, recursion, return

Aspiring programmer here, whilst doing some challenges on coderbyte I came across a little problem that I can't seem to solve. The challenge is as follows;

- Find the largest value in an array and check if any combinations of the other ints (excluding the largest number) amounts to that largest number. Return true if a combination has been found, false otherwise.

I got the all the parts of the question down, except the returning part. Which you'd think it's the easiest part.. Not for me though. Here's the code:

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr, largest, partial) {  
    var n, sumPart, remaining, largestI, result;

    // declace the next partial array, or start with an empty one
    partial = partial || [];

    // find the largest value from the original array,
    //  use the existing one if already declared
    largest = largest || arr.reduce(function(max, cur) {
    if(cur>max) return cur;
        else return max;
    });

    // sum up possible combinations of the partial array
    sumPart = partial.reduce(function (a, b) {return a + b;}, 0);

    // sumPart equal to largest int? return true
    if(sumPart === largest) {
        console.log("%s=%s", partial.join("+"), largest);
        return true;
    }

    // sumPart more than desired number? Stop
    if(sumPart > largest) {
        console.log("%s>%s", partial.join("+"), largest)
        return;
    }

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        n = arr[i];
        if(n != largest) {
            remaining = arr.slice(i + 1);
            ArrayAdditionI(remaining, largest, partial.concat([n]));
        };
    };
 return false;
};

// keep this function call here 
// to see how to enter arguments in JavaScript scroll down
ArrayAdditionI([4,6,23,10,1,3]);
```

It logs the correct answer(s) according to the first -if statement-, however, it never logs the "**true**" no matter what I seem to do. On the one hand I can see this returning false everytime since it's at the end of the function. On the other hand shouldn't this return true as soon as it meets true? Had this problem before, time to find out how to actually see this, and thereby fix it...

Comment: I'm not sure why you really want this but you could call console.log(ArrayAdditionI([4,6,23,10,1,3])). The reason why true isn't logged is because the function is returning true but it currently isn't been logged to the console.

Comment: The function needs to return true or false, doesn't necessarily have to be logged to console, that was just for checking purposes. The problem is, no matter what, the function returns false even if there's a sum that's equal to the largest number.